# Changing registry permission

Tags: c#, permissions, registry

I want to change the permission of a registry key, and I want to set it as a read only. How can I do this?

I tried this way, but it doesn't change anything:

```
RegistryPermission rp = new RegistryPermission(
    RegistryPermissionAccess.Read,
    "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\paci_1\\identity\\ASPNET_SETREG"
);
rp.AddPathList(
    RegistryPermissionAccess.Read,
    "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\paci_1\\identity\\ASPNET_SETREG"
);
```

Also, how can I do it for a user or administrator or owner etc?

Answer (score 3):

I think the class you want is RegistrySecurity. It's documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Security.AccessControl.RegistrySecurity.aspx).

It should look something like this:

```
using(RegistryKey rk =   
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\paci_1\identity\ASPNET_SETREG") )
{
    string gname = Environment.UserDomainName + @"\" + Environment.UserName;   
    RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
    rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(gname, RegistryRights.ReadKey, AccessControlType.Allow));
    rk.SetAccessControl(rs);
}
```

Of course, you would replace `gname` with the domain-qualified username of your choice.

Comment: Do make sure that you call `Dispose` on `rk` (or wrap its creation in a `using` statement).